# ACTION_VOICE_COMMAND doesn't do anything

Tags: android

I'm using this code snippet to activate voice command on android.

```
  Intent newIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VOICE_COMMAND);
    newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(newIntent);
```

it doesn't do anything, not even an error in my log cat:

```
06-03 13:26:24.325 203-822/? D/audio_hw_primary: out_set_parameters: enter: usecase(1: low-latency-playback) kvpairs: routing=2
06-03 13:26:24.335 203-822/? D/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: out_snd_device(2: speaker) in_snd_device(0: none)
06-03 13:26:24.335 203-822/? D/msm8974_platform: platform_send_audio_calibration: sending audio calibration for snd_device(2) acdb_id(15)
06-03 13:26:24.335 203-822/? D/audio_hw_primary: enable_snd_device: snd_device(2: speaker)
06-03 13:26:24.338 203-822/? D/audio_hw_primary: enable_audio_route: apply and update mixer path: low-latency-playback

    --------- beginning of system
06-03 13:26:26.277 786-892/? D/ConnectivityService: notifyType CAP_CHANGED for NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 100]
06-03 13:26:27.551 203-822/? D/audio_hw_primary: disable_audio_route: reset and update mixer path: low-latency-playback
    disable_snd_device: snd_device(2: speaker)
```

when I run this in ADB, it brings the google assistant up:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VOICE_COMMAND
```

which is weird, it's technically the very same thing.
is there permission i'm missing or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[From Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VOICE_COMMAND)

> Activity Action: Start Voice Command.

So to bring up the voice command assistant activity, Use `startActivity`as

```
getApplicationContext().startActivity(newIntent);
```

instead of

```
getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(newIntent);
```

like

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VOICE_COMMAND);
newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getApplicationContext().startActivity(newIntent);
//                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

> is there a way for the UI not to come up and cover my UI? or at least
>   for google assistant to go away after it listened and acted on my
>   voice command?

You can use [Google Assistant Service sdk](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/overview) and here is the [android quick start guide](https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/android.html)

Comment: is there a way for the UI not to come up and cover my UI? or at least for google assistant to go away after it listened and acted on my voice command?

Comment: apparently , I don't know any documentation to achieve this though you can integrate the SDK (more code but functionality)